# When to use std::move() for std::string?

Tags: c++11

This is a bit loaded question since after reading about std::move(), I am more confused.
std::move() will cast a variable to an rvalue.

My question.

1. Does it make any sense to use std::move for primitive data type like std::string.

Now, if yes. Here is my code

```
std::string val;
Mypersist store();
store.restore(val);
setAttribute(val);
//after this I don't care about val. 


int Mypersist::store(std::string &value)
{

}

void setAttribute(const std::string &value)
{

}
```

I am already using reference rather than value copy so I am a bit confused if std::move makes sense here or not.

I have this in my mind.

Is using std::move(val) for setAttribute will help in performance?
If so why?

```
std::string val;
Mypersist store();
store.restore(val);
setAttribute(std::move(val));
//after this I don't care about val.
```

Comment: `std::string` is not a primitive data type. It's essentially little different from `std::vector<char>`. Yes, it totally makes sense to use move semantics with it, where applicable. However, the way `setAttribute` is declared, it won't take advantage of move semantics - it takes its parameter by const reference and so can't possibly change it. `setAttribute(val)` and `setAttribute(std::move(val))` would work exactly the same; in either case `val` will not be moved from.

Comment: `Mypersist store();` declares a function named `store` taking no parameters and returning `Mypersist`. `store.restore(val);` would then fail to compile, as functions don't have members.